# Camera dark outline (passepartout) not working

Tags: camera

I am a new blender user and I'm following a bunch of tutorials to learn about the tool. I recently came across a camera tutorial and ran into a minor problem. After selecting the camera, I was changing the type and scale and wanted to reset the cursor position and pressed Shift + C. Instead of changing the position, it removed the dark border around the camera. How do I restore it back to its default view? Also, is it any different to remove the dark border? screenshot for details: https://bmoondesign.d.pr/XmbHGb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just pressed <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then you changed your view to show all objects in the scene. To get back into camera perspective press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

If you disabled the passepartout instead, select the camera and check *Passepartout* in the camera tab. The setting has no influence on the rendering only on the display in the viewport.

[image]

[image]